# How to read Pycharms parameter hinting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pycharm, reduce

I'm finding it hard to understand what the parameter hinting in Pycharm actually means in the below case.

Can someone please explain..

Why is the function callback wrapped as an array?
Why is there an `[*, optional]` array as well?

[image]

Comment: Can you show what the method definition of `reduce` as well?